# How do I pick a minimum from "version" convention?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to pull each AppId's lowest and highest appVersion;

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16kAWT6Ld9LC9IOWt0dTEfsINofgP73BzN-pjDq_9VnM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for helping!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77MQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This formula should give you a list with all the unique apps and their lowest version.

```
=Arrayformula(iferror({unique(A2:A), vlookup(unique(A2:A), sort({A2:B, substitute(B2:B, ".",)}, 3, 1), 2, 0)}))
```

See if that works for you ?

In case you don't want the appId to show, you can try

```
=Arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A2:A), sort({A2:B, substitute(B2:B, ".",)}, 3, 1), 2, 0)))
```

UPDATE: based on new info on the comments, try this formula to list the minimum and the maximum appversion per appId.

```
=Arrayformula(iferror({unique(A2:A), {vlookup(unique(A2:A), sort({A2:B, substitute(B2:B, ".",)}, 3, 1), 2, 0), vlookup(unique(A2:A), sort({A2:B, substitute(B2:B, ".",)}, 3, 0), 2, 0)}}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JPV
That's not actually what i'm looking for.

I'll try to simplify it down;
say I have few appVersions; I want to pull the min of them;

appversion    
1.1.0    
0.3.1  0 What i get using min() 
0.9.5    
0.6.4  0.3.1 What I want to get 

[updated the sheet]

Comment: I don't get it. As per your question you want "need to pull each AppId's lowest appVersion;". Isn't that what the formula I posted earlier returns ? I updated the screenshot with the new data you entered in your spreadsheet (as I can't edit it directly). Can you tell me in what way the output differs from what you expect ?

Comment: Thanks again for helping.
I was trying to cut the lines. the actual end result is a bit trickier.

I edited the sheet to show what exactly i need to do.
Thanks so much for helping!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16kAWT6Ld9LC9IOWt0dTEfsINofgP73BzN-pjDq_9VnM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Updated my answer to meet the new requirements.